# How Can I make relationship between two entities below?

Tags: database, relational

Currently I am designing  entity relationship diagram which is a bank account. I handled most of the part but I have a problem with the entities  called `Account` and `Transaction` I didn't get the relationship in the instruction which is as follows

> Each account can have zero or many transactions and each can appear zero or many times as source or destination on money transfer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can a transaction ever be between more or less than two accounts, or does it always strictly have a "from" and a "to" account?

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Can there be a transaction between three accounts? Or a transaction that involves only one account? Or do all transactions have a sum, an account it's trasferred from and and account it's transferred to?

Comment: Yes it can be between  more than one account.

Comment: Mureinik is right; it is not clear whether every transaction is a money transfer between two accounts. In an account-to-account transaction there are two accounts: where the money comes from and where the money gets to. Of course you can have many transactons for one account. So the relation is 2:n. But it is not specified wheher there can be other transactions like deposit and withdrawel where there would only be one account in the transaction.

Comment: Here is full question it may help :Accounts are identified by currency type which is one of the existing currencies in the database , IBAN, balance, blocked balance and opening
date. Each account can be owned by one customer as private account or by multiple customers as sheard account. Each account can have zero or many transactions and each can appear zero or many times as source or destination on money transfer.

Comment: From a relational perspective there is no reason that a many-to-many intersection table can't use the same account number (thus handling withdrawals).  The intersection (or resolution) table would consist of things like source_account_id, target_account_id, transaction_id, transaction_number (nothing more than a grouping operator if there is more than one account - like an allocation - to a transaction), transaction_type, transaction_amount, transaction_date, transaction_enacted_by, transaction_base_currency.

Comment: To reiterate:  From a relational perspective there is no reason that a many-to-many intersection table can't use the same account number (thus handling withdrawals). The intersection (or resolution) table would consist of things like source_account_id, target_account_id, transaction_id, transaction_number (nothing more than a grouping operator if there is more than one account - like an allocation - to a transaction), transaction_type, transaction_amount, transaction_date, transaction_enacted_by, transaction_base_currency.